# How can I get more creative with styling in CSS

Tags: css

I'm working on my own website at the moment, and i need to be more creative with the fonds and the major display on my website. Is there any website that is very good to get inspiration from as a rookie in web development and web design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). It's a good front-end design framework that is easy to use, responsive, and looks pretty good. You can see examples of sites made with Bootstrap if you click on Expo.

Comment: Bootstrap, if anything, defeats creativity by giving you pretty much everything you need, ready-made.

Comment: @BoltClock I completely agree with you.

Comment: Just a suggestion for discovering what is possible and current. Perhaps it does prevent pure creativity, but it could help inspire and the ease of use allows someone very inexperienced to tinker with it at least.